# Tomcat8 is running but the status is Tomcat servlet engine is not running

Tags: linux, debian, tomcat8

I'm confused about how tomcat is working now.

When I try to start it `"sudo service tomcat8 start"` or `"sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat8 start"` I get an error `"[FAIL] Starting Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat8 failed!"`. No errors in logs.

If I execute `"sh catalina.sh run"` I get

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat8/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Unable to load server configuration from [/usr/share/tomcat8/conf/server.xml]
May 26, 2017 8:05:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

If I execute `"sh startup.sh"` I get

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Only after execuiting `"sh startup.sh"` my project works. BUT, the status is

```
sudo service tomcat8 status
[ ok ] Tomcat servlet engine is not running..
```

WTF??? **Any Ideas?**

It all worked perfectly yesterday until I launched the script. This script we use in another projects and it works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
#v2.5

url="jenkins/ROOT.war"

stop="/etc/init.d/tomcat8 stop"
start="/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start"
tmp_dir="/tmp/new-version"
tomcat_dir="/var/lib/tomcat8"
app_dir="$tomcat_dir/webapps"
cache="$tomcat_dir/work/Catalina"
log="$tomcat_dir/logs/catalina.out"

tomcat_user="tomcat"
tomcat_user="$tomcat_user"
log_dir="/var/log/new-version"
backup_dir="/home/tomcat"

if [ "$url" = "" ]; then
    echo "${url}"
else
    mkdir -p $log_dir
    rm -rf $tmp_dir
    mkdir -p $tmp_dir/ROOT
    cd $tmp_dir/ROOT
    application_file=$(echo $url | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\)/\1/')
    echo $application_file
    mv $application_file ROOT.war
    jar xf ROOT.war 2>&1 >> $log_dir/`date +%F`.log
    rm -rf ROOT.war
    jar cf ROOT.war *
    mv ROOT.war $tmp_dir/ROOT.war
    cd $tmp_dir
    echo "revision is prepared. Deploy it and restart tomcat?[y/n]"
    read answer

    if [ "$answer" = "y" ]; then
    $unmonitor
    sh $stop

    mv -f $log $log.`date +%F`.rev.$old_revision
    rm -rf $app_dir/ROOT $app_dir/ROOT.war $cache

    mv ROOT.war $app_dir/ROOT.war
    touch $log
    chown -R $tomcat_user:$tomcat_group $app_dir
        sh $start
    $monitor
        echo "Revision $new_revision is up and running!"
    echo "Now compressing old logs..."

        tar czf $log.`date +%F`.rev.$old_revision.tgz $log.`date +%F`.rev.$old_revision
    rm -rf $log.`date +%F`.rev.$old_revision
    cd ~
    rm -rf $tmp_dir

    echo "Done!"
    else
    echo "Aborted!"
    fi
fi
```

Server info

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
```

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, I didn't. I had to uninstall tomcat8 and install tomcat9. But the script hasn't been launched yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at this line `chown -R $tomcat_user:$tomcat_group $app_dir` where it is using tomcat user=tomcat instead of tomcat user=tomcat8. I changed webapps directory permissions not for my tomcat8 user.